# Java - Get server absolute path

Tags: java, file, tomcat, glassfish

How to get the absolute path of server location in my machine?

Suppose I am using glassfish server then I need to get absolute path of glassfish docroot location as below:

```
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot
```

At run time, I need to create file on that location using java io package like:

```
C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot\myfile.txt
```

Comment: Look at [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) for methods like `getRealPath(path)` & `getContextPath()`.

Comment: request.getRealPath("") or request.getServletContext().getRealPath("") gives me C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ServletExamples\build\web

Comment: @user966709 u r getting that path probably because from NetBeans u have configured hot deployment.. but if u really create a .war file and deploy it you would probably get the path to docroot

Answer (score 5):

If you use GlassFish to start GlassFish, i.e. use `asadmin start-domain|start-instance` then we offer the following iron-clad guarantee:

The current working directory of the JVM is absolutely, positively guaranteed to be the config directory of the domain or server.  In the default case that would be:

```
c:/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/config
```

If you want to write something to (the default) docroot, you can do this:

```
File f = new File("../docroot/yourfile");
```

---

Another option that is guaranteed to always work in every scenario even if you start the server with java directly (e.g. `java -jar glassfish.jar`) is to use the value of the System Property like so:

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("com.sun.aas.instanceRoot") + "/docroot/yourfile");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had an similar problem and ended up with using

```
path = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()
```

because I needed the path on a static function. This points somwhere to the WEB-INF/classes directory. With this you could point to something like `path.subString(0,path.indexOf("WEB-INF"))`.

One problem that I had with this: When running a test from Eclipse, it pointed me to the "build" directory of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best way, but it works for me :)

```
String path = new File("").getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "docroot";
```

Comment: This gets the path of the place where you started the application server, usually the place where the startup.sh/startup.bat is located. This script might not be necessarily inside the server folder.

Answer (score 1):

you can try following:

```
System.getProperty("catalina.base");
```

And you can find other properties by watching following variable in debug mode.

```
Properties properties = System.getProperties();
```

Comment: specific to the particular web server

Comment: but as i can see, the asker of question uses glassfish. so it will be usefull for him/her.

Comment: I tried to do this but sadly I didn't find any absolute path to reveal my servers' root. Do you know how to determine it? (I used the second code and printed in out via logging).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very bad idea. If you are running in a WAR or EAR file the docroot will not be on a  writable filesystem. Assuming this is the case may lead to headaches later.

Use a different method, such as a servlet initialization parameter, to specify a writable filesystem location.

Answer (score -1):

For that you need not to go for complete path because

when you are creating file than by default it will create at `ROOT` of you server

which is `C:\glassfish3\glassfish\` here.

hope this will help you.

Comment: Currently I am using hard coded path C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot for writing file on that location, but need to get dynamically because if some other person will use application then may be his glass fish server exist in d:\ directory and In this case he needs to manually change path.

Comment: Write code in java 
File file = new File("/domains/domain1/docroot/myfile.txt"); 
this will create file at C:\glassfish3\glassfish\domains\domain1\docroot\myfile.txt even your glassfish in c:\ or d:\ doesn't matter.